# How to identify tr id less than a predifned one?

Tags: jquery

I have following html table layout:

```
    <table id="price" class="print" crit="Medicine" scrit="2016">
    <thead><tr><th>S/N</th><th>Generic Name</th><th>Trade Name</th><th>Company</th><th>Buy Rate</th><th>Sell Rate</th><th>MRP</th><th>Action</th></tr></thead>

    <tbody>
    <tr id="111"><td>1</td><td>Aceclofenac 100mg&nbsp;Tablet</td><td>Caclotin</td><td>Reneta</td><td>1.80</td><td>3.80</td><td>4.00</td><td><a class="btn edit result ebar" href=""></a></td></tr>

    <tr id="259"><td>2</td><td>Albendazole 400mg&nbsp;Tablet</td><td>Pernil DS</td><td>Euro Pharma</td><td>2.45</td><td>5.00</td><td>5.00</td><td><a class="btn edit result ebar" href=""></a></td></tr>

    <tr id="113"><td>3</td><td>Allyestrenol&nbsp;Tablet</td><td>Gestrenol</td><td>Reneta</td><td>5.00</td><td>8.00</td><td>8.00</td><td><a class="btn edit result ebar" href=""></a></td></tr>

    <tr id="33"><td>4</td><td>Ambroxol Hydrochloride 100ml&nbsp;Syrup</td><td>Myrox</td><td>ACI</td><td>23.85</td><td>38.00</td><td>40.12</td><td><a class="btn edit result ebar" href=""></a></td></tr>

    <tr id="305"><td>5</td><td>Amoxycillin Trihydrate 500mg&nbsp;Capsule</td><td>SK-Mox 500</td><td>Eskayef</td><td>3.45</td><td>6.00</td><td>6.00</td><td><a class="btn edit result ebar" href=""></a></td></tr>

    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Now by ajax, a new row is to be inserted. The new row also has an id and the new row will be inserted after the id which is less than the new row id. Lets understand by example:

```
    <tr id="35"><td>59</td><td>Vitamin-E 200mg&nbsp;Capsule</td><td>E-Gel</td><td>Reneta</td><td>2.00</td><td>4.00</td><td>4.01</td><td><a class="btn edit result ebar" href=""></a></td></tr>
```

You can see, id of the new row is 35, so it should be inserted after the row id 33 (Ambroxol Hydrochloride 100ml Syrup).

For this reason, at first, I have to identify tr id (here 33) which is less than the new row id (Here 35). Then I can easily insert the new row after prevRow (which has id 33).

```
var prevID = $('table#price > tbody > tr').filter(function() {
  var thisId = parseInt(this.id, 10);
    return thisId < cbdata.trid; //callback id (here 35)
}).last().attr('id');
```

The above jquery code is unable to find the less than id, if tr ids are not sequential, i.e tr ids are 111, 259, 113, 33, 305. It is working only if the tr ids are 33, 111, 113, 259, 305 sequence (ascending or descending order).

How to get less than retrieved id if the existing html table row's ids are not in ascending or descending order?

Comment: N:B- Please don't tell me that ids could not be starting with digit. Please overlook this point.

Comment: numbers **are** valid ids, just for your peace of mind

Comment: @AbdullahMamun-Ur-Rashid check below given solution I think this is your requirement.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I tested different jQuery codes to find a tr id which is less than a retrieved id. All of your response are excellent, specially @DelightedD0D did a lot. But I developed a code for this purpose which is, according to me, simple and effective in all cases.

The code is below:

```
$("body").on("click","table#price > tbody > tr",function(){
var newId = 35;
var prevId = 0;
  $("table#price > tbody > tr").each(function(){
    var thisId = parseInt(this.id,10);
    if(thisId<newId){
      if(thisId>prevId){
        prevId=thisId;
      }
    }
  });
alert('Previous id is: '+prevId); 
});
```

If you found any error in this code, please report it here.

Answer (score 1):

This would work:

```js
function addRow(newId, newRow) {
  // itterate all current rows getting their ids in an array
  var $tbody=$('#price').find('tbody');
  var trIds = $.map($tbody.find('tr'), function(element) {
    return Number(element.getAttribute('id'));
  })
  //add 0 to the beginning of the trIds array before we call reduce
  //this ensurse that if no number in the array is less than the new number, 0 will returned, dont use 0 is an actual id anywhere.
  trIds.unshift(0);
  var cur = trIds.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
    return (Math.abs(curr - newId) < Math.abs(prev - newId) && curr < newId ? curr : prev);
  });
  var $closestLessThanTr = $('#' + cur);
  // here we first check if there is an element with this id, if not, then our new element is the lowest id and should be added at the top of the container
  $closestLessThanTr.length > 0 ? $(newRow).insertAfter($closestLessThanTr) : $tbody.prepend(newRow);
}

var newIdValue = 35; // get this from your not-shown code somewhere
var newRowHtml = '<tr id="35"><td>59</td><td>Vitamin-E 200mg&nbsp;Capsule</td><td>E-Gel</td><td>Reneta</td><td>2.00</td><td>4.00</td><td>4.01</td><td><a class="btn edit result ebar" href=""></a></td></tr>'; // get this from your not-shown code somewhere

addRow(newIdValue, newRowHtml);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="price" class="print" crit="Medicine" scrit="2016">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>S/N</th>
      <th>Generic Name</th>
      <th>Trade Name</th>
      <th>Company</th>
      <th>Buy Rate</th>
      <th>Sell Rate</th>
      <th>MRP</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr id="111">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Aceclofenac 100mg&nbsp;Tablet</td>
      <td>Caclotin</td>
      <td>Reneta</td>
      <td>1.80</td>
      <td>3.80</td>
      <td>4.00</td>
      <td>
        <a class="btn edit result ebar" href=""></a>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="259">
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Albendazole 400mg&nbsp;Tablet</td>
      <td>Pernil DS</td>
      <td>Euro Pharma</td>
      <td>2.45</td>
      <td>5.00</td>
      <td>5.00</td>
      <td>
        <a class="btn edit result ebar" href=""></a>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="113">
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Allyestrenol&nbsp;Tablet</td>
      <td>Gestrenol</td>
      <td>Reneta</td>
      <td>5.00</td>
      <td>8.00</td>
      <td>8.00</td>
      <td>
        <a class="btn edit result ebar" href=""></a>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="33">
      <td>4</td>
      <td>Ambroxol Hydrochloride 100ml&nbsp;Syrup</td>
      <td>Myrox</td>
      <td>ACI</td>
      <td>23.85</td>
      <td>38.00</td>
      <td>40.12</td>
      <td>
        <a class="btn edit result ebar" href=""></a>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="305">
      <td>5</td>
      <td>Amoxycillin Trihydrate 500mg&nbsp;Capsule</td>
      <td>SK-Mox 500</td>
      <td>Eskayef</td>
      <td>3.45</td>
      <td>6.00</td>
      <td>6.00</td>
      <td>
        <a class="btn edit result ebar" href=""></a>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Your code is excellent but not working in all cases. If there is id#36 in html table, then it is calculating closest id as 36 instead 33. I have created a fiddle for this purpose. Please check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/infomamun/52jw0ro7/1/

Comment: @AbdullahMamun-Ur-Rashid I have edited my answer back to it's original state. I liked that the reduce method was a good bit shorter but you're right, it fails in that case. Here is an updated [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/52jw0ro7/2/) using my original method. The longer method should work in all cases, Ill go back and look into how to fix the reduce method when I have a bit more time.

Comment: please look into the reduce method or any other shorter method in your convenient time and let us know.

Comment: @AbdullahMamun-Ur-Rashid Updated with a new reduce method and added logic to handle when the new element is actually the lowest id in the group

Comment: I developed a code for this purpose. Please see my another answer in this topic below.

Answer (score 0):

try this, just set

> var newRowID = 3;
>   to your new id instead of 
>   3

```js
$(function() {
  var allIds = [];
  $("table tr[id]").each(function(i) {
    allIds.push(this.id);
  });

  allIds.sort();

  var newRowID = 3;
  var closest = allIds.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
    return (Math.abs(curr - newRowID) < Math.abs(prev - newRowID) ? curr : prev);
  });

  
  $("table tr[id='" + closest + "']").after("<tr><td><h2>no data</h2></td></tr>")



});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="price" class="print" crit="Medicine" scrit="2016">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>S/N</th>
      <th>Generic Name</th>
      <th>Trade Name</th>
      <th>Company</th>
      <th>Buy Rate</th>
      <th>Sell Rate</th>
      <th>MRP</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr id="111">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Aceclofenac 100mg&nbsp;Tablet</td>
      <td>Caclotin</td>
      <td>Reneta</td>
      <td>1.80</td>
      <td>3.80</td>
      <td>4.00</td>
      <td>
        <a class="btn edit result ebar" href=""></a>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="259">
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Albendazole 400mg&nbsp;Tablet</td>
      <td>Pernil DS</td>
      <td>Euro Pharma</td>
      <td>2.45</td>
      <td>5.00</td>
      <td>5.00</td>
      <td>
        <a class="btn edit result ebar" href=""></a>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="113">
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Allyestrenol&nbsp;Tablet</td>
      <td>Gestrenol</td>
      <td>Reneta</td>
      <td>5.00</td>
      <td>8.00</td>
      <td>8.00</td>
      <td>
        <a class="btn edit result ebar" href=""></a>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="33">
      <td>4</td>
      <td>Ambroxol Hydrochloride 100ml&nbsp;Syrup</td>
      <td>Myrox</td>
      <td>ACI</td>
      <td>23.85</td>
      <td>38.00</td>
      <td>40.12</td>
      <td>
        <a class="btn edit result ebar" href=""></a>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="305">
      <td>5</td>
      <td>Amoxycillin Trihydrate 500mg&nbsp;Capsule</td>
      <td>SK-Mox 500</td>
      <td>Eskayef</td>
      <td>3.45</td>
      <td>6.00</td>
      <td>6.00</td>
      <td>
        <a class="btn edit result ebar" href=""></a>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution your problem is in finding the closest number to the id.
Find the below fiddle to understand the procedure of how to add the new row at the desired position.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/52jw0ro7/)

For finding the id which is closest to the Element.

```
var closest = ids.reduce(function (prev, curr) {
  return (Math.abs(curr - goal) < Math.abs(prev - goal) ? curr : prev);
});
```

**Edit**

As pointed out that the previous solution is having limitations I have worked out another logic for getting the desired output.

What m I do ?

Making an array of ids and adding the new id to the array then sorting the ids getting the index of the id and based on that adding the new row.

Here is the working fiddle. [Method 2](https://jsfiddle.net/52jw0ro7/4/)

Hope this will solve your issue.

- Help

Comment: Very nice approach to solving the crux of the issue. +1, I hope you dont mind, but I have updated my own answer to incorporate this method.

Comment: Saddly, this actually does not function as expected, It will find the closest number in the array higher or lower.